# Java Comparator : possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java, ооп

Нужно сравнить значения double c помощью Comparator. Мой код:

```
class CompareShapePerimetr implements Comparator<IShape>{
    @Override
    public int compare(IShape o1, IShape o2){
        return o1.getPerimetr()-o2.getPerimetr();
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что данное действие выдает ошибку

> Incompatible types:  possible lossy conversion from double to int

Как можно избавиться от этой ошибки, или сравнить значения double с помощью Comparator или Comparable.

Простите, я новичoк и не очень понимаю тему...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (int) Math.signum(o1.getPerimetr() - o2.getPerimetr());
```